# How to change the underline color of the input component in MD Bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend, mdbootstrap

So I'm using the [Input Group Component](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/docs/4.0/bootstrap-components/input-group/#sizing) from [MDBootstrap.](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/)

I was wondering if there's a way around for changing the color of the blank of the input field component in MD Bootstrap. Like at the moment, it looks like this (without focus):

[image: Input Field Componentme without focus]

When I click on this input field, it looks like this (with focus, the color of the input field blank changes to green):

[image: Input Field Component with focus]

The code for the this component is as follows:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-lg">Name</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Large" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
</div>
```

I was wondering if there's a way around for changing the color of the input field blank to black instead of green when we click on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **backgroundImage** style with `<input />` would work

Try it in-text:

```js
const style = {
  backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(0deg, black 2px, rgba(0, 150, 136, 0) 0),
    linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26) 1px, transparent 0)`
};
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-lg">
            Large
          </span>
        </div>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          aria-label="Large"
          style={style}
          aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-wXznGJNEXNG1NFsbm0ugrLFMQPWswR3lds2VeinahP8N0zJw9VWSopbjv2x7WCvX"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

---

The step to achieve it:

If you check the style in the browser,

You would find that color with animation, copy it and change that color, and that's it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the border bottom:

```
.md-form .form-control#form1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f48fb1;
}
```